# Add each list element to beginning of each row in numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am just learning how to use the numpy matrix function and I am running into a problem.

I have a list of n integers, and a matrix of n rows. I need to add each number from the list to the beginning of its corresponding row in the matrix.

So if I have the following matrix and list:

```
m = np.matrix([[0, 13], [13, 0]])
myList = [10, 11]
```

My desired output is this:

```
newMatrix = [[10, 0, 13],
             [11, 13, 0]]
```

Here's the code I have so far (trying to replicate the last example on [this page](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html)):

```
for c in range(len(myList)):
    newMatrix = np.insert(m[c],[0],myList[c])
```

But this of course only gives the last iteration of the for loop ([11, 13, 0]). I would like to somehow append each row to a new matrix but I can't seem to figure that out.

EDIT: The length of the list and the matrix will not always be known.

If anyone more experienced with numpy matrices knows a better way to do this, I would really appreciate it! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to reshape your `myList` and then use `np.concatenate()` function:

```
import numpy as np

np.concatenate((np.array(myList).reshape(len(myList),1), m), axis = 1)
# matrix([[10,  0, 13],
#         [11, 13,  0]])
```

You can also do:

```
np.concatenate((np.array(myList)[:, None], m), axis = 1)

# matrix([[10,  0, 13],
#         [11, 13,  0]])
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response! I forgot to mention that I am trying to write a function that will work for a list and matrix of any length. From my research on reshape, it seems that you need to specify the size of your matrix? (I will edit my question to include this restriction.)

Comment: Just saw your edit: of course, this works perfectly. Thanks again!!

Comment: Just updated the answer, as long as the length of `myList` and the number of rows of the matrix are the same, this should work for any list and matrix.

Answer (score 2):

my solution is:

```
import numpy as np

m = np.matrix([[0, 13], [13, 0]])
myList = [10, 11]
newmatrix = np.insert(m, 0, myList, axis=1)
```

the output is:

```
[[10  0 13]
 [11 13  0]]
```